# Minesweeper: I want to set my mines in 2 dimensional array. How can I check it?

Tags: c#

So I'm making a console minesweeper game. The mines are stored inside a 2 dimensional array called "mineLoc". I'm not sure if it's stored properly and I don't know how to access this array to check.

```
public void MinesSetter(int height, int width)  //to generate mines randomly        
{
    int mineCount = 0;
    int numOfMines = (height*width) / 8;
    Random random = new Random();

    do
    {
        int minePosY = random.Next(height);
        int minePosX = random.Next(width);
        int[,] mineLoc = new int[minePosY,minePosX];
        mineCount++;
    } while (mineCount <= numOfMines);

    _minesSet = !_minesSet;                       
    Console.WriteLine($"There are {numOfMines} mines ");
}
```

Comment: You're declaring a new array on every iteration of the `do` loop, and then it is destroyed after the loop ends. You should probably declare the array outside the `do` loop, and return it from the method.

Comment: Also, before you place a new mine at some position, you need to check whether that position is already occupied

Comment: `new int[minePosY,minePosX]` is not setting a position, but declaring a new (0-filled) array of the specified size

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. As Rufus pointed out in the comments, you need to declare you array outside of the loop, else it will be overwritten on each iteration.
2. You need to check whether a cell is already marked as mine, so that you don't count it again.
3. A mine can sufficiently be presented with a `bool`, `int` is unnecessary.

Your code would look something like this:

```
public void MinesSetter(int height, int width)  //to generate mines randomly        
{
    int mineCount = 0;
    int numOfMines = (height*width) / 8;
    Random random = new Random();
    bool[,] mineLoc = new bool[minePosY,minePosX];    

    do
    {
        int Y = random.Next(height);
        int X = random.Next(width);

        if(!mineLoc[X, Y])
        {
          mineLoc[X, Y] = true;
          mineCount++;
        }

    } while (mineCount <= numOfMines);

    Console.WriteLine($"There are {numOfMines} mines ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

every time your "do...while" loop iterates, your code is defining new "fresh" mineLoc[,] table. It is probably the problem you're looking for.

Comment: I am sure you could give a lot more information and detail in your answer to help OP. Don't forget to format your answer to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create the array outside the `do` loop, populate it inside the loop, and then return it.

When we populate it, we should check to see if the random numbers we've chosen have not already been chosen.

In the example below, we're using `0` to represent no mine, and `1` to represent a mine:

```
private static readonly Random random = new Random();

public static int[,] MinesSetter(int height, int width)       
{
    int mineCount = 0;
    int numOfMines = height * width / 8;
    var results = new int[width, height];

    do
    {
        int minePosX = random.Next(width);
        int minePosY = random.Next(height);

        // Make sure we haven't already set this position
        if (results[minePosX, minePosY] != 1)
        {
            results[minePosX, minePosY] = 1;
            mineCount++;
        }
    } while (mineCount <= numOfMines);

    return results;
}
```

In use this might look like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Get a 10x10 grid with random mines
    var mines = MinesSetter(10, 10);

    // Display the grid (with mines visible)
    for (int row = 0; row < mines.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < mines.GetLength(1); col++)
        {
            Console.Write(mines[row, col] + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's *extract* the array as a *field* to be able to address it within other methods:

```
  // Field: we can address mineLoc from any (non static) method within class
  private int[,] mineLoc = new int[0, 0];

  private Random random = new Random();

  private void MinesSetter(int height, int width) {
    mineLoc = new [height, width]; 

    int mineCount = 0;
    int numOfMines = (height * width) / 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMines; ++i) 
      // Simplest, not guarantee, that we have exactly numOfMines
      mineLoc[random.Next(height), random.Next(width)] = 1; // mine
  } 

  private int NumberOfMines {
    get {
      int count = 0;

      // now we can address mineLoc within a property...   
      foreach (var item in mineLoc) 
        if (item == 1) 
          count += 1;

      return count;
    }
  }  

  private bool IsMineAt(int y, int x) {
    // now we can address mineLoc within a method...   
    if (y >= 0 && y < mineLoc.GetLength(0))
      if (x >= 0 && x < mineLoc.GetLength(1)) 
        return mineLoc[y, x] == 1;

    return false; 
  }
```